# Other has permissions with umask 007 on VM with mounted folder

Tags: fedora, permissions, directory, umask

One thing that's odd to me right now is I am playing around with permissions. The way umask works to my knowledge is it basically tells what permissions `u` `g` `o` don't have using octal representation (subtracting from 6 on files and 7 in directories). So I thought that **007** should leave `u=rwx g=rwx o=` for directories and `u=rw g=rw o=` for files

However that is not what's happening on my vm (Fedora29). Here is what I do and what I get

```
$ umask 007
$ mkdir test-d
$ touch test-f
$ ls -l

drwxrwxr-x. 1 vagrant vagrant 4096 Feb 18 16:35 test-d
-rw-rw----. 1 vagrant vagrant    0 Feb 18 16:35 test-f
```

So the file works as expected but there's still `r-x` on the directory for "other". Any idea why that is?

This behaviour only happens in the folder I synced with my host machine (which is also running on Fedora29) but it does not seem to just use the umask from the host machine. If I change my host machine to 007 `o` will still receive `r-x`.

Comment: one think I found out is this. My default umask is 002 before changing it which would add to be rwxrwxr-x for folders. however my folder is definately created in 007 and i still get o=rx

Comment: What does `ls -Zd .` return in the directory where you did these things?  There seems to be an SELinux security context on the current folder (the `.` at the end of the permission string).

Comment: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 .
I just found out something I didn't mention before. The folder I tried this is mounted to my host machine (also fedora29) when I do this in another folder it works as expected. Didn't think it would make a difference before. Will add it to the question

Comment: is `mkdir` wrapped? what is the output of `type -a mkdir` ? (suspecting a `mkdir -m 775 ...`)

Comment: sorry for the late reply. just returned. type -a mkdir -> mkdir is /usr/bin/mkdir